# How to add multiple hostnames in private DNS zone in Azure to resolve hostnames for VNET?

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, azure-networking, hadoop, endpoint

I have an AKS (Azure Kubernetes cluster) that is on a VNET (Azure Virtual Network) that needs to connect to multiple On-prem hadoop machines to read/write data. I have a private DNS zone connected to VNET to resolve hostnames to IP - I tested with a couple of them and it works.

The problem is I have about 900 machines I need to connect and resolve them (These are present in my hosts file and I can read data when tested locally).

In Azure private DNS zone I need to add hostnames one by one manually. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two ways (afaik) to achieve this - use native powershell azure commands [DOCS HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dns/?view=azps-8.2.0#dns), or the [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/) if you prefer other languages ;)